# Forcing highlight to return all array items

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an array of string in an index. By default, highlight returns only array items with highlighted segments. But I need to get all array items in the highlight section.

request:

```
{ "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "title": {}
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": "Super"
    }
  }
}
```

response:

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_source": {          
      "title": [
        "Iphone cover",
        "Super mega iphone cover"
      ],           
    },
    "highlight": {
      "title": [
        "<em>Super</em> mega iphone cover"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I want to have the following highlight section instead:

```
"highlight": {
      "title": [ 
        "Iphone cover",   
        "<em>Super</em> mega iphone cover"
      ]
    }
```

So I can determine what array item was highlighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment. There is a [discussion about this feature on GitHub](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7416), but it didn't come to a conclusion yet.